# How to aggregate pandas dataframe timestamps columns from days to years, calculating weighted average

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, aggregation

I'm working with a pandas dataframe with the following format:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'Col_1': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'FFF', 'FFF'], 
'Col_2': ['BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'GGG', 'GGG'], 
'Col_3': ['CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'HHH', 'HHH'], 
'Col_4': ['DDD', 'DDD', 'DDD', 'III', 'III'], 
'Col_5': ['EEE', 'EEE', 'EEE', 'JJJ', 'JJJ'], 
'validity_start': ['2008-01-01', '2008-08-01', 
'2009-09-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-04-01'], 
'validity_end': ['2008-07-30', '2009-08-30', 
'2010-12-31', '2011-03-31', '2012-12-31'], 
'Value': [111.10128, 222.28392, 333.28392, 444.46656, 555.34547]
})
```

I need a help to aggregate the value column with weighted average by year (considering `validity_start` and `validity_end` number of days per year as weights), and grouping by columns from `col_1` to `col_4`. The result should like this table:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'Col_1': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'FFF', 'FFF'], 
'Col_2': ['BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'GGG', 'GGG'], 
'Col_3': ['CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'HHH', 'HHH'], 
'Col_4': ['DDD', 'DDD', 'DDD', 'III', 'III'], 
'Col_5': ['EEE', 'EEE', 'EEE', 'JJJ', 'JJJ'], 
'YEAR': ['2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'], 
'Value': ['157.7066', '259.3853', '333.2839', '527.7772', '555.3455']
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe the weighting function?

Comment: the weighting function considers the number of elapsed days for a given year. eg: let's consider the first 2 rows of the input dataframe: the weighted average for 2008 considering validity_end - valitdity_start +1 days as the weight for the value for row1, and the weight for row 2 should be a timestamp operation '2008-12-31' - '2008-08-01' + 1 days. i need to create a function that applies this idea for all years within this grouped range. I tried groupby, but then I'm stuck (perhaps i should use resample, but i don't know how to do this with categorical groupby). Thanks for your support.

Comment: So one row in the output needs to consider data from multiple rows in the input?

Comment: Yeap, and the inverse is also true. The output rows must be reshape in years, so one input row can be split in multiple rows depending on validity start and validity end (multiple years in this input row dates range), and many input rows can also be consolidated in one output row (if we have the same year in many input rows). Is there a method that reshape irregular dates intervals into years, and weights another column by the elapsed days of the years included in these ranges ? Or should I create a personalized loop, checking row by row ?